# MSQL Error Code: 1031. Table storage Engine for '#sql-13C0_31' doesn't have this option

Tags: mysql

I have spent time trying to adjust the options / configuration to get around this problem. I could surely use some assistance. I'm using MySQL v5.7.19 and should be using storage engine=InnoDB. I've not tried to import data into the table illustrated below. Strictly created the table and then altering the table to create partitions.

Here is the Show Create Table:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    assetInformation_TB (
        aiEnId              bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiId                bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiParentId          bigint  UNSIGNED    NULL,
        aiInternalId        varchar (32)        NOT NULL, 
        aiExternalId        varchar (32)        NOT NULL, 
        aiDestEligDate      date                NULL, 
        aiIntransit         boolean DEFAULT FALSE NOT NULL, 
        aiCurrentLocation   varchar (32)        NOT NULL, 
        aiRfidTag           varchar (32)        NOT NULL, 
        aiBarcode           varchar (32)        NOT NULL, 
        aiShortDesc         varchar (64)        NOT NULL, 
        aiLongDesc          varchar (4096)      NOT NULL, 
        aiExternalRef1      varchar (32)        NULL, 
        aiExternalRef2      varchar (32)        NULL, 
        aiExternalRef3      varchar (32)        NULL, 
        aiExternalRef4      varchar (32)        NULL, 
        aiStorageType       varchar (3)         NOT NULL, 
        aiStorageClass      varchar (3)         NOT NULL, 
        aiIsReconciled      boolean             DEFAULT FALSE  NOT NULL, 
        aiAgId              bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiAhId              bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiAhLevelNbr        integer UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiAmtId             bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiAtId              bigint  UNSIGNED    NOT NULL, 
        aiRsId              bigint  UNSIGNED    NULL,
        aiStatus            smallint UNSIGNED   DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL, 
        aiCreatedOn         timestamp           DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL, 
        aiCreatedBy         bigint UNSIGNED     DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL, 
        aiModifiedOn        timestamp           DEFAULT current_timestamp       
                                    ON UPDATE current_timestamp NULL, 
        aiModifiedBy        bigint UNSIGNED     DEFAULT 0   NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY         (aiEnId, aiId)
    )

    COMMENT 'Asset Information Table'

    ENGINE = InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

The first partition, but there are 89 others:

```
ALTER TABLE assetInformation_TB 
    PARTITION BY RANGE (aiEnId + aiId) PARTITIONS 90 (
            PARTITION DBP001_0 VALUES LESS THAN (18246999999999999999) 
                ENGINE=InnoDB 
                DATA  DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\DBP' 
                INDEX DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\IDX'
            ,
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

> [22.6 Restrictions and Limitations on Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-limitations.html)
>
> On Windows, the DATA DIRECTORY and INDEX DIRECTORY options are not
>   supported for individual partitions or subpartitions of MyISAM tables.
>   However, you can use DATA DIRECTORY for individual partitions or
>   subpartitions of InnoDB tables.

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE `assetInformation_TB`
    ->   PARTITION BY RANGE (`aiEnId` + `aiId`)
    ->   PARTITIONS 1
    ->   (
    ->     PARTITION DBP001_0 VALUES LESS THAN (18246999999999999999)
    ->     ENGINE=InnoDB
    ->     DATA DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\DBP'
    ->     INDEX DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\IDX'
    ->   );
ERROR 1031 (HY000): Table storage engine for '#sql-3aa3_4' doesn''t have this option

mysql> ALTER TABLE `assetInformation_TB`
    ->   PARTITION BY RANGE (`aiEnId` + `aiId`)
    ->   PARTITIONS 1
    ->   (
    ->     PARTITION DBP001_0 VALUES LESS THAN (18246999999999999999)
    ->     ENGINE=InnoDB
    ->     DATA DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\DBP'
    ->     -- INDEX DIRECTORY = 'f:\proga1d\ad03\DBP001_0\IDX'
    ->   );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```